# Tensorflow Multi-GPU performance is not good

Tags: tensorflow

We try to implement Tower method but found the performance become worse:

1. Modified from:
   https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception
2. Devices:

   - Intel Core i7
   - GTX-1060 x 2
3. Source code:

   - Splitting=None : default version
   - Splitting=True : tower version

```html
from tensorflow.python.ops import tensor_array_ops
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
import tensorflow as tf
import tflib as lib
import numpy as np
import time
BATCH = 64
DIM = 1000
GPUs = 2

Splitting = True

def init_matrix(shape):
  return tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)

def Block(param, x, name, reuse):
  W  = tf.get_variable('%sweight'%name, [DIM, DIM])
  b  = tf.get_variable('%sbias'%name, [DIM])
  if not reuse: param.extend([W, b])

  x_ = tf.reshape(x, [-1,DIM])
  output = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x_, W) + b)
  return tf.reshape(output,[-1,DIM,DIM])

def _tower_loss(param, inputs, reuse=None):
  with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=reuse):
    output = Block(param, inputs, 'Layer.0.', reuse)
    output = Block(param, output, 'Layer.1.', reuse)
    output = Block(param, output, 'Layer.2.', reuse)
    output = Block(param, output, 'Layer.3.', reuse)
    output = Block(param, output, 'Layer.4.', reuse)
    output = Block(param, output, 'Layer.5.', reuse)
    output = tf.reshape(output, [-1, DIM*DIM])
    return tf.reduce_mean(output)

def _all_gradients(tower_grads):
  all_grads = []
  for i in range(len(tower_grads[0])):
    for grad in tower_grads:
      grads = []
      expanded_g = tf.expand_dims(grad[i], 0)
      grads.append(expanded_g)
    grad = tf.concat(axis=0, values=grads)
    grad = tf.reduce_sum(grad,0)
    all_grads.append(grad)
  return all_grads

if not Splitting:
  opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-4, beta1=0.5, beta2=0.9)
  inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[BATCH,DIM,DIM])

  param = []
  loss = _tower_loss(param, inputs, None)
  grad, _  = tf.clip_by_global_norm(tf.gradients(loss, param), 5.0)
  apply_gradient_op = opt.apply_gradients(zip(grad, param))
  merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

  with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(".", session.graph)
  
    for i in range(100):
      start = time.time()
      session.run(apply_gradient_op,feed_dict={inputs:np.zeros([BATCH,DIM,DIM])})
      print 'Iter'+str(i)+': time='+str(time.time()-start)

else:
  with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-4, beta1=0.5, beta2=0.9)
 
    inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[BATCH,DIM,DIM])
    inputs_splits = tf.split(axis=0, num_or_size_splits=GPUs, value=inputs)

    param = []
    tower_grads = []
    reuse = None
    for i in range(GPUs):
      with tf.device('/gpu:%d'%i):
        with tf.name_scope('Tower_%d'%i) as scope:
          with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
            loss = _tower_loss(param, inputs_splits[i], reuse)
          reuse = True
          grad, _  = tf.clip_by_global_norm(tf.gradients(loss, param), 5.0)
          tower_grads.append(grad)
    grads = _all_gradients(tower_grads)
    apply_gradient_op = opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, param))
    merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

    with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as session:
      session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
      writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(".", session.graph)
      for i in range(100):
        start = time.time()
        session.run(apply_gradient_op,feed_dict={inputs:np.zeros([BATCH,DIM,DIM])})
        print 'Iter'+str(i)+': time='+str(time.time()-start)
```

4. Performance:

   - Default version - use only GPU:0

     time=0.867873907089
   - Tower version - tried to use multi-GPU

     time=4.88468384743

Our question is:

1. It shows 5 time slower with the Tower method. Is there anything wrong in our implementation?
2. Based on the tutorial, we save model in the CPU and split tasks to different GPU. But our GPU connects with each other via PCIe, not NVLink. Frequently data transferring cost a lot. Is there any alternative can help PCIe-based multi-GPU?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(GPUs):
  with tf.device('/gpu:%d'%i):
    with tf.name_scope('Tower_%d'%i) as scope:
      with tf.device('/cpu:0'):  ### this line may cause all op allocated on cpu, try remove this line 
        loss = _tower_loss(param, inputs_splits[i], reuse)
      reuse = True
```

Comment: Remove 'with tf.device('/cpu:0')' did improve! Thanks. But it still take around time=0.908358812332 to execute, similar to the single GPU results. Do you have idea about this?